# CSS-only version of com_content in Joomla

Tags: php, css, joomla

Has anyone built a version of the com_content Joomla 1.5 component? I've got a table-free design but don't want to now introduce ugly tables from the content. Are there any alternative component that is pure CSS? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the com_content in the Beez template, it is tables free.

Also, all (I think) template overrides in that template are tables free; I used it as the base for my templates and made the appropriate changes.

Comment: Thanks, jackJoe. I've been trying to round up all the CSS used by that template's com_content override and wasn't sure what CSS classes I needed to throw into my template's CSS file. Any thoughts?

Comment: At a first glance, your template index.php will contain most of the tags and so most of the customized CSS, so no need to add any, but the overrides (and in this case taking the example of the Beez template) will contain the "regular" classes, such as "contentpagetitle", "iteminfo" and so on; open the desired override and you'll see the classes, or even better (that's what I would do) apply the override and check the html rendered (use firebug (with firefox) for instance).